# Set value of const before testing a method which relies on it

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have several methods in a `utils.js` file, one relies on a const in the same file. I would like to write a test in which the const value is something other than that which is set in `utils.js` (simplified for demonstration purposes):

```
//------------------------------------------------
// utils.js
//------------------------------------------------

import { someMethod } from './services';

export const MY_CONST = someMethod(); // boolean

export function doThing() {
  return MY_CONST;
}
```

```
//------------------------------------------------
// utils.spec.js
//------------------------------------------------

import { MY_CONST, doThing } as Utils from './utils';

test("test default doThing", () => {
  expect(doThing()).toEqual(false); // ---> passes
}

test("test doThing with a different const value", () => {
  jest.doMock('./utils', () => ({ MY_CONST: true}));
  expect(doThing()).toEqual(true); // ---> fails, still false
})
```

Alternatively, I have tried `spy`, `spyOn`, as well as:

```
//------------------------------------------------
// utils.spec.js
//------------------------------------------------

const UtilsMock = jest.requireMock('./utils');
jest.mock('./utils', () => ({
  MY_CONST: false,
}));

test("test doThing with a different const value", () => {
  UtilsMock.MY_CONST = true;
  expect(doThing()).toEqual(true); // fails, still false
})
```

I have also tried targeting the `someMethod` itself so that it returns `true` in the test but have had the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing `utils.js` module, you should not mock it. Instead, you should mock `services.js` module and `someMethod` function. Besides, we should require or dynamic import the module after `jest.doMock()`.

`utils.js`:

```js
import { someMethod } from './services';

export const MY_CONST = someMethod(); // boolean

export function doThing() {
  return MY_CONST;
}
```

`services.js`:

```js
export const someMethod = () => false
```

`utils.spec.js`:

```js
describe('73941884', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const mServices = {
      someMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
    };
    jest.doMock('./services', () => mServices);
    const { doThing } = require('./utils');
    expect(doThing()).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73941884/utils.spec.js (10.185 s)
  73941884
    ✓ should pass (9565 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 utils.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.807 s, estimated 11 s
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful and I believe that it's the correct answer. However, it still did not work in my particular use case and I think that's because I tried to oversimplify. `doThing` called another method, which also referred to `MY_CONST`, which was still evaluating as `false`, so we probably would have needed to mock those as well.  
  
Anyway, the relevant blocks have since been refactored and these related tests are now being discarded. Womp.